# Django, path/urls

Tags: python, django

please explain me why following code works with http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1/ and doesn't for http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/:

mysite\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('index/', include('polls.urls')),
  path('1/', include ('polls.urls')),
]
```

polls\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('1/', views.polls, name='z'),
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Does Django not accept absent of some indexlike path, is everything built on it?

Comment: What do you mean by "code doesn't work for ..."? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: it shows view for '1/' only if it goes after 'index/', in the address, like 127.0.0.1:8000/index/1, and it doesn't recognize just 127.0.0.1:8000/1/, I get 404

Comment: The full error message of the yellow debug page will tell you which paths Django tried, which will help explain what is going on. Make sure you have saved all your files and restarted the server so that you are running the code you think you are.

Comment: I've checked again, so: for 127.0.0.1:8000/index brings index view(correct), for 127.0.0.1:8000/1 also index view(not correct), and for 127.0.0.1:8000/index/1 it renders view for /1(correct). Why it recognize(shows right view) /1 only in case of /index/1? The path for '/1' pattern goes before ' ' pattern(for index), so it should be caught first.

Answer (score 2):

try to use your urlpatterns in mysite to use only one path, and then map the paths inside your polls/url.py like this

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

and polls/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('1/', views.polls, name='z'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

if you are using class based views (CBV's) make sure to use .as_view() in your urlpatterns :) hope this helps!

Comment: it should be polls/1 and poll/ will give you the index

Answer (score 1):

As per your code all your paths will be,
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1/` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/1/` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/`

From these the two urls associated with polls in your views.py are  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/1/`

As you have mentioned in your title `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1/` works and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/` does not is because you are requesting wrong url. The url you are requesting is not for views.polls change it to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/1/`. You will get your desired result.